# In Firefox Quantum, how can I get rid of the tab bar, want Tree Style Tabs only

Tags: firefox

I'm a long time user of the "Tree Style Tabs" add-on of Firefox.  As a matter of fact it is *the* reason why I use Firefox

Firefox automatically upgraded to their new version, Firefox Quantum.  Now there's an annoying bar of tabs across the top which is redundant because the Tree Style Tabs also puts the tabs on the left.

Is there a way I can disable tabs on the top bar?  If not, is there a way I can go back to an old version of Firefox and not have it update to Firefox Quantum?

Comment: I followed this link, and it worked. https://superuser.com/questions/1261660/firefox-quantum-ver-57-how-can-i-hide-the-horizontal-tab-bar-with-treesty/1261661?newreg=22fbb15ea1384d19b9c4eda1d99c131a

Comment: Yup.  same link posted in the answer that I wrote below to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through further research I realized that my question is a duplicate of the one posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1261660/firefox-quantum-ver-57-how-can-i-hide-the-horizontal-tab-bar-with-treesty/1261661).

The answer there worked for me, though it was a bit of a pain (requires creating a text file in a magic place, and the first time I tried I put it in the wrong place).  It would be nice if this was a configuration option provided in Firefox's menus.